# Analytic functions on $\mathbb T$ (Katznelson's Ex $1.4.4$)

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The following exercise appears in Katznelson's *Harmonic Analysis*.

> Show that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb T$ if and only if there exist constants $K>0$ and $a>0$ such that $|\widehat f(j)|\le K e^{-a|j|}$.

Of course, the analyticity of $f$ is defined in the usual sense - a function $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb T$ if in a neighborhood of every $t_0 \in \Bbb T$, $f(t)$
can be represented by a power series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(t-t_0)^n$.

---

1. For the first direction, suppose $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb T = \Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, i.e., for every $t_0 \in \Bbb T$, $f$ can be represented by a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(t-t_0)^n$. How should I produce the exponential bound on the Fourier coefficients? I have considered using the compactness of $\Bbb T$, to come up with finitely many points $t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_k$ and subsets $U_0,U_1,\ldots,U_k$ such that $t_i \in U_i$ for each $1\le i\le k$, the $U_i$'s are disjoint, and $\Bbb T = \bigcup_{i=0}^k U_i$. Then,
   $$|\widehat f(j)| = \left|\int_\Bbb T f(t) e^{-2\pi i jt} \ dt\right| \le \sum_{i=0}^k \left|\int_{U_i} f(t) e^{-2\pi i jt} \ dt \right|$$
   Also, there are constants $\{a_{n,i}\}_{0\le i\le k, n\ge 0}$ such that $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n,i}(t-t_i)^n$ on $U_i$, so $$\int_{U_i} f(t) e^{-2\pi i jt} \ dt = \int_{U_i}e^{-2\pi i jt}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n,i}(t-t_i)^n \, dt$$
   I'm stuck here.
2. Another approach for the first direction - as $f$ can be locally represented by a power series, $f$ is infinitely differentiable, and so $\widehat f(j) = o(j^{-k})$ for all $k\in \Bbb N$, i.e., $\lim_{|j|\to\infty} j^k \widehat f(j) = 0$ for all $k \in \Bbb N$. This shows that the Fourier coefficients have faster-than-polynomial decay, but it doesn't immediately imply the required exponential decay.
3. I'm clueless about the other direction.

I'd appreciate any hints or solutions - thank you!

---

*Related*: [Post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276251/fourier-coefficients-are-exponentially-bounded-for-a-real-analytic-periodic-fun).

Comment: We have that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_n z^n$ is analytic in a neighborhood of the circle, hence in an annulus with inner radius $r<1$ and outer radius $R>1$; the part with $n>0$ is analytic then on a disc with radius $R>1$ so $|a_n|K^n \to 0$ for any $1<K<R$ hence the result with $a=\log K>0$ for them; similarly for negative index coefficients using $z\to 1/z$; conversely the exponential decay implies $\sum a_nz^n$ analytic on an annulus containing the unit circle hence the fourier series is analytic

Comment: @Conrad Could you add more details, perhaps in an answer? I'm not sure why you consider the sum over all integers, and what the said power series is meant to represent.

Comment: I think what you want to look at is the [Laurent expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) of an analytic function, which gives a representation in the form that @Conrad used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketching an answer as requested, we note that $f$ originally defined on the unit circle is complex analytic there (in the sense that for any point on the unit circle, there is a converging power series representing $f$ on this neighborhood) if and only if $f$ extends to a holomorphic function in an annulus $1/R <|z| <R$ for some $R>0$. This follows from the compacity of the unit circle, so we can cover it with finite many disks where such power series exists etc

But a function $f$ is analytic on $1/R < |z| <R$ if and only if it has a Laurent series $f(z)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z}a_n z^n$ converging (locally uniformly and absolutely on any compact within) and considering $z=e^{i\theta}$, it follows that $a_n$ are precisely the Fourier coefficients of the original $f$ on the unit circle.

But now for $n \ge 0$ we have that $\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$ is a converging regular power series in $|z| < R$ so for any $1<\rho<R$ we have $|a_n|\rho^n \to 0$ so the estimate required holds with $a=\log \rho >0$

Similarly $\sum_{n \ge 0}a_{-n}z^{-n}$ converges on $|z| >1/R$ so with $w=1/z$ we get that $\sum_{n \ge 0}a_{-n}w^{n}$ converges on $|w| <R$ so we have the same estimate $|a_{-n}|\rho^n \to 0$ for the coefficients indexed by negative integers and we are done with one implication.

Conversely, if the required estimate holds and we take $R =\log a$ it follows that the Laurent series $g(z)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z}a_n z^n$ converges on $1/R <|z| <R$, hence is analytic there and since now $a_n$ are the Fourier series of $f$ (which also converges to $f$ by the given estimates on the unit circle), it follows that $g=f$ on the unit circle, so $g$ is the required analytic extension of $f$ and we are done!